# More difficult proof of limit whose value is e^x

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the real sequence:
$$a_n:=(1+x/n)^n$$
Now prove that there exists an $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ (just prove that $\alpha$ exists, no need to find the value) such that:
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge N,|a_n-\alpha|<\epsilon$$

This should be done strictly with basic algebra; no logarithms, no Taylor series, no derivatives, and $e$ shouldn't appear anywhere in the proof.  I suspect that the Bernoulli inequality will probably be useful.  Considering the limitations, is there a concise way to show this?

Comment: Hint: First show that it holds for any $x$ from the existence of $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+1/n)^n.$

Comment: Bernoulli is the key here. You should first prove that the limit exists for $x=1$ (this is famous and should be known to you). Use algebraic manipulation to show that if the limit exists for $x=1$ it exists for all rational $x$.

Comment: And by the way you do some some analysis and not just algebraic manipulation. In particular you need the theorem that *any bounded monotone sequence is convergent*.

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404327/72031 extension to irrational $x$ is based on the fact that the sequence is eventually monotonically increasing and if $a, b$ are rationals with $a<x<b$ then the sequence is bounded above by $e^b$ or $e^a$.

Answer (score 3):

**MONOTONICITY**

In [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using Bernoulli's Inequality that $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is monotonically increasing for $x>-n$.

---

**BOUNDED ABOVE**

Using the binomial theorem, we have for $x>-n$

$$\begin{align}
0&\le\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\\\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac xn\right)^k\right|\\\\
&=\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \prod_{\ell=1}^{k-1} \left(1-\frac{\ell}{n}\right)\frac{x^k}{k!}\right|\\\\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{|x|^k}{k!}\\\\
&\le \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|x|^k}{k!}
\end{align}$$

where the ratio test guarantees that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{|x|^k}{k!}$ converges for every $x$.

---

**CONCLUSION:**

Inasmuch as $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ is bounded above and monotonically increasing for each fixed $x$, then it converges for each fixed $x$.

And we are done!